# Unable to access view to change background color

Tags: java, android, view

I am building a simple list view that is taking in a series of detected items and adding them to a list. I want to be able to change the color of these views when I click on them. However, I am struggling with creating a way to access the individual view so that I can change its color. This code is based off Android Studio Sample BluetoothLeGatt. I have tried looking at places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881520/unable-to-access-views-in-android) to no avail.

**Class adding detected device to the list**

```
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0) {
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            } else {
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            }
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
            return view;
        }
    }
```

**OnListClick Code**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null) return;
    getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
//change background color here.
}
```

Here I supposedly able to access the individual elements with **getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);** but I don't know how to use this to change the background color since it doesn't provide me access to the view itself.

**XML for ViewList**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could suggest a way to alter Android Studio's implementation I would greatly appreciate it. I am trying to use this code due to my unfimiliarity with Android Development.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting View parameter at second in this method

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```

**If you want change onTouch color the use this**

Make a `bg.xml` in your `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" /> 
  </selector>
```

Set this drawable to parent layout element

```
<LinearLayout
    background="@drawable/bg"    
    clickable="true"
    ...>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

OnListClick Code you have (view v)
Using this v you can access properties related to clicked view.